Mark table with swipe gesture on mobile phone
I have the following code:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>24-Hour Time Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>48-Hour Time Table</h1>
    <table>
        <tbody id="time-list">
            <!-- Rows will be added here by JavaScript -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

styles.css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

script.js
const createTimeList = (elementId) => {
    const container = document.getElementById(elementId);
    const now = new Date();

    for (let i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
        const date = new Date(now.getTime() + i * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
        const formattedTime = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':00';

        const row = document.createElement('tr');

        const indexCell = document.createElement('td');
        indexCell.textContent = i + 1;
        row.appendChild(indexCell);

        const timeCell = document.createElement('td');
        timeCell.textContent = `${formattedDate} - ${formattedTime}`;
        row.appendChild(timeCell);

        const checkboxCell = document.createElement('td');
        const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkboxCell.appendChild(checkbox);
        row.appendChild(checkboxCell);

        container.appendChild(row);
    }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    createTimeList('time-list');
});

This code already works as desired.
I would now like to extend it so that it is possible to mark several lines on the mobile phone in a simple way using a swipe gesture. So I swipe from the second to the tenth line with my finger to mark them all.
Unfortunately, I can't find anything online that could help me.
I tried different code blocks i found for javascript, but nothing works for my case.
